# SQL Server - parse parent-child structured JSON with unknown depth in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, parent-child, sql-server-2016

I'm going to ask my last question which has left unanswered, how can I list all the objects in following JSON string having parent-child structure?

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) =
' {
    "topparent": [{
        "id": "1"
        , "parent": "0"
        , "child": [{}]
    }, {
        "id": "2"
        , "parent": "0"
        , "child": [{}]
    }, {
        "id": "3"
        , "parent": "0"
        , "child": [{
            "id": "4"
            , "parent": "3"
            , "child": [{
                "id": "5"
                , "parent": "4"
                , "child": [{
                    "id": "6"
                    , "parent": "5"
                    , "child": [{}]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "7"
        , "parent": "0"
        , "child": [{}]
    }, {
        "id": "8"
        , "parent": "0"
        , "child": [{}]
    }, {
        "id": "9"
        , "parent": "0"
        , "child": [{}]
    }]
 }'
```

None of approaches I know work. I used Common Table Expression:

```
 ;with cte
 as
 (
    select *
    from openjson(@json, '$.topparent')
    with (
        id int
        , parent int
        , child nvarchar(max) as JSON
    ) p

    UNION ALL

    select r.*
    from cte e
    inner join openjson(e.child)
    with (
        id int
        , parent int
        , child nvarchar(max) as JSON
    ) r
    on r.parent = e.id
 )
 select * from cte
```

But the error is given: The multi-part identifier "e.child" could not be bound.

I also tried cursors but loops come with performance issues.
How can I list all the children without knowing how deep they can go?

Comment: Im afraid, if you do not know the depth of a such structure, you will not have any better choice than to use cursors or recursion. Such tasks are costly by their nature.

Comment: Exactly, I can do it with cursor but cursors cause poor performance, maybe I'll find a way by using small functions, I'll work on it today, if found any results I'll post it here